# Extract values corresponding to top k of any other column

Tags: r, join, data.table

How do I get in one table, he values of 'x' corresponding to top k values of 'y' and of 'z' ?

```
> dt <- data.table( x = letters[c(1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1)],
                    y = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1), z = c(1, 2, 3) )
> dt
   x y z
1: a 1 1
2: a 2 2
3: c 1 3
4: b 2 1
5: c 2 2
6: a 1 3
7: a 1 1
```

Can this case be solved with a join, or must I loop over the columns which are not 'x'?

```
> requested.output
   var x Val
1:   y a   2
2:   y b   2
3:   y c   2
4:   z c   3
5:   z a   3
6:   z a   2
```

Comment: Shouldn't 4 5 and 6 rather be
4: z a 3
5: z b 1
6: z c 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to loop or join, you can simply convert to a long format according to the `x` column, sort by `value` in decreasing order, and select the first 3 rows according to each `variable`.

```
melt(dt, id = "x")[order(-value), .SD[1:3], keyby = variable]
#    variable x value
# 1:        y a     2
# 2:        y b     2
# 3:        y c     2
# 4:        z c     3
# 5:        z a     3
# 6:        z a     2
```

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is interested in a `dplyr` and `tidyr` solution.

```
dt %>%
    gather(variable, value, -x) %>%
    group_by(variable) %>%
    filter(row_number(-value)<=3) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    arrange(variable, desc(value))

##      x variable value
##  (chr)   (fctr) (dbl)
##1     a        y     2
##2     b        y     2
##3     c        y     2
##4     c        z     3
##5     a        z     3
##6     a        z     2
```